# Why should I give `savetxt` a file opened in binary rather than text mode?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I was bitten by the following `numpy` behaviour:

```
In [234]: savetxt(open('/tmp/a.dat', 'wt'), array([1, 2, 3]))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-234-2adef92da877> in <module>()
----> 1 savetxt(open('/tmp/a.dat', 'wt'), array([1, 2, 3]))

/local/gerrit/python3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in savetxt(fname, X, fmt, delimiter, newline)
   1007         else:
   1008             for row in X:
-> 1009                 fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
   1010     finally:
   1011         if own_fh:

TypeError: must be str, not bytes

In [235]: savetxt(open('/tmp/a.dat', 'wb'), array([1, 2, 3]))
# success
```

I find this strange. I'm trying to save my array to a *text* file. Then why should I open the file in *binary* mode?

Comment: Maybe this is a bug in Numpy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your data is bytes (ie binary) data.

What comes out is still a text file. Don't worry. :-) A "text" file is defined a something that contains only human readable text, not by in which mode you open it. The mode just makes a difference in how it handles the data given.

Text mode means it expects Unicode data, and it will encode it into bytes format for you. Binary mode means it expects data in bytes, and will not encode it.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely because numpy maintainers have not updated this function to be fully compatible with python 3.  A name "savetxt" certainly implies a text-only file would be adequate, and there's nothing preventing them from calling fh.write((format % tuple(row) + newline).encode()).

There's nothing wrong with using binary mode, either, except that it leads to a surprise in some cases, as you've discovered.  I consider it a bug in api design if nothing else.