# python3-numpy: Appending to a file using numpy savetxt

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, save, append

I am trying to append data to a file using numpy's savetxt function. Below is the minimum working example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
f=open('asd.dat','a')
for iind in range(4):
    a=np.random.rand(10,10)
    np.savetxt(f,a)
f.close()
```

The error that I got is something about the type of the error

> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1073,
>   in savetxt
>       fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline)) TypeError: must be str, not bytes

This error doesn't occur in python2 so I am wondering what the issue could be. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You have to open your file in binary instead of text mode: `f=open('asd.dat','ba')`. Also consider using the `with` statement to ensure that your file handle gets properly closed in case an error occurs.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437054/why-should-i-give-savetxt-a-file-opened-in-binary-rather-than-text-mode.

Answer (score 50):

You should open file by binary mode.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np        
f=open('asd.dat','ab')
for iind in range(4):
    a=np.random.rand(10,10)
    np.savetxt(f,a)
f.close()
```

reference:
python - How to write a numpy array to a csv file? - Stack Overflow [How to write a numpy array to a csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659814/how-to-write-a-numpy-array-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: Was looking a long time for this 'ba' option. Thanks.

Comment: 'b' option didn't work with np.savetxt on my machine. Can anyone confirm it?

Comment: @HyunjunKim My python (python-3.5, numpy-1.13.3 on Ubuntu 16.04) work well above code. If you try string, append data type (`np.savetxt(f, ["AAA"], "%s")`)

Comment: @user4352571 I thought 'b' option is for writing data in unreadable format by human. But the code above doesn't work without 'b' option. Sorry for my misunderstanding.