# Writing floating point numbers to a file in "ab" mode

Tags: python, file

I am using Python 3.5 64bit Windows OS. I am trying to write floating point values to a file. This is the code

```
 with open('report.txt' , "ab") as f:
      f.write(b"\n Result Pattern\n")
      f.write('%f' %test_accuracy)
```

I have tried the new `'{}'.format` specifier as well. However I get the following error

```
f.write('%f' %test_accuracy)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

So, how do I specify a format for writing digits , when the file mode is binary. Another point is that, I get an error if I try to write without the binary option.

Update:
I am aware of basic file writing in python and when to use `b`. I have this snippet of numpy code where I am writing the array to the file as well.

```
            np.savetxt(f , test_pat ,
                   header = 'A , B , C , D , E' ,
                   comments='' ,
                   delimiter = ',' ,
                   newline = '\r\n' ,
                   fmt = '%3d')
```

I get the aforementioned error at this point with error message as:
`fh.write(asbytes(comments + header + newline))
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes`

It is then when I switch the mode to `ab` strangely the error goes away.

Is the `\r\n` a problem while trying to have it formatted nicely when opened through a notepad?

**Another update:**

Similar error and the answer suggest using `binary` mode!
[numpy savetxt append mode error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786868/python3-numpy-appending-to-a-file-using-numpy-savetxt)

Comment: `f.write(b'%f' %test_accuracy)` This? You need `b` here too.

Comment: I don't understand, why are you writing in binary mode, when it looks like you want a text-file anyway?

Comment: You need to deiced which file type you want. You currently seem to be trying to mix text and binary. That won't work. Choose one and stick to it. In this case as @juanpa.arrivillaga said, it really doesn't even look like you need binary.

Comment: Well, what do you know!, That was the first thing I tried , but was getting an 'Unknown format code b' error, but somewhere in my code I had missed adding the 'b' option and that messed it up. Thank you for your lightning fast response. I needed a third eye really to correct my error. My error is solved now.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I did try without the binary option, but I get the 'write() argument must be str, not bytes' error. Strange, it should occur.

Comment: @WilbusFugu because then you need to not use a binary literal, i.e. leave out the `b'...'` from the literal... you should really try to understand *why* you are getting these errors.

Comment: @WilbusFugu That's because you're opening your file in the wrong mode. Wait, let me write an answer.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Yes, I do not specify the  `b` while opening. Its the standard `with open('file.txt' , 'a') as f`. I have not specified the binary mode in my strings yet I get the `write() argument must be str not bytes` error

Comment: @ChristianDean uh, yes, *I* understand that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I know what `b` means. Did you read my comments?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Oh crap, I think you know I screwed up there :| Let's try that again.

Comment: @WilbusFugu Remember, you can only mark one answer accepted.

Comment: I apologize @Wilbus if my comment seemed condescending. That was not my intention. When I asked "do you understand"? that was not to imply your lack of intelligence. I was simply asking so I could know whether I should provide you with a link to a relevant section of documentation. Regardless, I deleted the comment seeing as you _do_ seem to understand. I meant no ill will.

Comment: @ChristianDean: Not a problem at all, and I apologize for misinterpreting {will delete my comment) it. I have updated the question with a similar error and using binary mode solved it like in my case.Am only curious if its somehow related to numpy's `savetxt' functionality and not the actual binary and text file semantics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
with open('report.txt', "ab") as f:
    f.write(b"\n Result Pattern\n")
    f.write(b'%f' %test_accuracy) # you need to add b here.
```

Comment: Welcome @WilbusFugu.  If the answer worked for you, please mark it as accepted by pressing the check mark on the left side of the answer, thanks!

Comment: This answer is a cookie cutout of [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667702/writing-floating-point-numbers-to-a-file-ab-mode-python/45667784#comment78292788_45667702). What more do you have to add to a comment?

Comment: How @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. ? Why you did not answer this question before comment ? Are you confused ?

Comment: I wrote an answer because I realised the OP's problem was required a deeper level of explanation to solve than just telling them to add `b`. I have mentioned it before, saying `Try this :` and posting code is not a helpful answer for future readers.

Comment: But his error is ocurring for only `b`. So, I think post helpful code is better than explain for this question.

Comment: StackOverflow appreciates answers that are "good" more than those that are "good enough". Keep that in mind.