# Appending to a .data file in python

Tags: python, file, types, append, file-extension

Similar to [Meenakshi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786868/python3-numpy-appending-to-a-file-using-numpy-savetxt) I am trying to append data to a file using numpy's savetxt function.

I have a .data file that I want to append more float32 data to.

```
responses = np.array(responses,np.float32)
responses = responses.reshape((responses.size,1))

# save as new training results
np.savetxt(sampleData,samples)
np.savetxt(responseData,responses)

# want the option to append to previously written results
```

I am able to append as binary with the following but I need to append in float32.

```
# append to old training results 
    with open(sampleData, 'ab+') as fs:
        fs.write(samples)
    with open(responseData, 'ab+') as fr:
        fr.write(responses)
```

When I try

```
# append to old training results 
        with open(sampleData, 'a+') as fs:
            fs.write(samples)
        with open(responseData, 'a+') as fr:
            fr.write(responses)
```

I get "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not numpy.ndarray"

What is the syntax/ extension I should be using to interact with this .data file type in python given the above?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What attributes is it saying don't exist?

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear :)

Comment: I updated my answer - saw the part about appending, which I missed before.

Answer (score 1):

## Update:

Didn't see your comment on appending originally. The [answer in your linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27980725/4739755) shows you were on the right track:

The following will append your data as expected, but without dumping "gibberish" (bytes). `np.savetxt` apparently takes care of doing the appropriate formatting/encoding so that what's written is human readable.

```
with open(some_file, 'ab+') as fo:
    np.savetxt(fo, responses)
```

#### Original - left here to explain why the OP approach wasn't working

Your comment hints into what's happening:

> The following does append but it inputs gibberish (i assume because of the binary, but without the b it tells me I need to input a string) --> with open(sampleData, 'ab+') as fs: fs.write(samples) with open(responseData, 'ab+') as fr: fr.write(responses)

When you try to write without `b`, it complains appropriately, because you *need* to give it a string in normal write-mode - you can't just write a list/array (which is what `samples` and `responses` are). When you use `b`, you're writing in binary/bytes mode, so whatever you pass to `write` gets coerced into bytes. This is what I see if I write the following in binary mode:

```
resp = np.array([1, 2, 4, 5], np.float32)
resp = resp.reshape((resp.size, 1))
np.savetxt(file1, resp)
with open(file2, 'ab+') as fo:
    fo.write(resp)

# From Hex view of written file
00 00 80 3F 00 00 00 40 00 00 80 40 00 00 A0 40
```

which is identical to calling `bytes(...)` on the array I made:

```
import binascii
binascii.hexlify(bytes(resp))

# produces:
b'0000803f00000040000080400000a040' -> '00 00 80 3f 00 00 00 40 00 00 80 40 00 00 a0 40'
```

So, you just need to format your data into a `str` friendly representation, such as joining into a string (for example):

```
>>> ', '.join(str(x) for x in resp)
'[1.], [2.], [4.], [5.]'
```

...but how you format it is of course dependent on your requirements.