# Why np.savetxt doesn't write anything?

Tags: python, numpy, csv, psycopg2

I'm appreciate to your help in my issue.

I want to append my response query into exist CSV file. I'm implement this by [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786868/python3-numpy-appending-to-a-file-using-numpy-savetxt) but from unknown reason - the output file stay empty.

This is minimal snippet of my code:

```
import psycopg2
import numpy as np

# Connect to an existing database
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="...", user="...", password="...", host="...")
# Open a cursor to perform database operations
cur = conn.cursor()

f = open('file_name.csv', 'ab') # "ab" for appending

cur.execute("""select * from table limit 10""") # I have another query here but it isn't relevant.
cur_out = np.asarray(cur.fetchall())
```

Until here it works perfect. When I `print(cur_out)`, I got desired output. But in the next step:

```
np.savetxt(f, cur_out, delimiter=",", fmt='%s')
```

The file stay empty and I didn't find the reason for that.

Can you help me please?

Thankes for helpers.

Comment: The accepted answer says they can't reproduce this, can you clarify the situation?

Comment: Don't know how say that. Probably that existing file interrupt my code run, so the file deleting solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to tell you. But your code works for me perfectly.

My suggestions:

1. If you have existing files in this name, try to delete them and execute your code again,
2. Try to change the batch size.
3. Try to change the postfix of the file name to txt or dat.

Best wishes.

Comment: @ficfic _It works._ Was it working all along, did one of the suggestions fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
np.savetxt('file_name.csv', cur_out, delimiter=",", fmt='%s')
```

Comment: This solution doesn't match to the problem. I want to append rows. This answer re-write the whole file.

Comment: this what np.savetxt do. you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30376581/save-numpy-array-in-append-mode for appending

Comment: @AlyHosny: His approach is good. the open in "a" mode should ignore re-create file.